# Django generating python file

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am building site in django and I have table with data:

```
<th>name</th>
<th>data</th>
```

`data` is necessary in my client-side python program `sender.py`.

User double click on specific row and using `pyinstaller` compile it with `data` which user selected stored as `const` in python program and then download it.

I manage to make JS script witch shows what row you selected, but I cant figure out how to insert `data` into python program, use run pyinstaller on that file and then download it.

Python program have function which takes that data but is not necessary

Python:

```
from somelib import func

constData = data

def clientFunc(constData):
    if constData != None or len(constData) <= 0:
        print("Argument constData is valid")
    else:
        constData = str(constData)
    client = func(constData, 9999)

    client.func2()
```

or

```
from somelib import func

constData = data

if constData != None or len(constData) <= 0:
    print("Argument constData is valid")
else:
    constData = str(constData)
    client = func(constData, 9999)

    client.func2()
```

JS:

```
const table = document.getElementById('table');

const rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

Array.from(rows).forEach((row, index) => {
  row.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    const cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
    console.log(cells[0]);
    console.log(cells[1]);

    const content1 = cells[0].innerHTML;
    alert(content1)
  });
});
```

I will be grateful for at least one of these things.
Cheers!

Comment: `raise print("Argument constData is valid")`?

Comment: Oh, i forgot about that dont bother